# Is it allowed to ask developers to complete a scientific survey on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, rules, research, guidelines

The title speaks for itself. We will be doing research on software documentation, part of this research consists of a survey targeted at software developers.

We would like to reach the developer community of Stack Overflow with our survey but we are not sure if asking the developers to complete the survey is against the guidelines.

Does anyone here have something helpful to say about this?

Comment: @Poly not a dupe, posting a question (or answer) is not the only way to ask people to do something. It's one way, and that other question perfectly covers this, but not the other ways.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I'd draw a distinction between "asking the developers to complete the survey" in a question and advertising the existence of a survey via other means.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are **not** allowed to ask directly via the below methods:

- Questions or answers asking to take part in the survey
- Comments asking to take part in the survey

However, you **can** do one of the following:

- Post it in your profile page About Me section, so those who read your profile will see it
- Buy advertisement and place it as external advertisement

Answer (score 3):

"Can you take our survey" is not itself a programming question (even if the survey touches on programming matters), and isn't something that will be at all helpful to future users.

In other words, it would be an abuse of the site to advertise such things as a question.